# Emacs on Mac for Python - python-mode keeps using the default Python version

Tags: python, emacs

how do I change the version of Python that emacs uses in the python-mode to the latest version that I just installed ?

I tried setting the PATH in my init.el file to the path where the latest version of python resides but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

Set the variable `python-python-command`. This can be done via `customize`:

1. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `python-python-command` <kbd>RET</kbd>
2. Change the value to point to the appropriate binary.

Comment: Similar to this problem, I tried using the sql-mysql mode but emacs is unable to find the file/directory mysql. However, I can access it from the terminal. How do I point mysql in emacs to /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql ?

Comment: That sounds more like a PATH issue, but it looks like you can customize a similar variable: `sql-mysql-program`.

Answer (score 0):

`PATH` is only searched when a program is launched via the shell.

For programs that are launched directly by Emacs (for example, via `call-process`), it's the `exec-path` variable that is searched.